# How to show loading screen while .DAE environment and characters are loading?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, game-development, collada

I am pretty new at SceneKit and the first thing I noticed is the time it takes to load a DAE environment and characters. I've been looking for ways to show a loading screen while the environment is loading but none of them seem to work.

Whenever I push from menu screen to game screen, it would show around half of the menu screen and half of the game's screen with the UIKit components, and after about 3 seconds, then it shows the game screen without finishing the push animation transition. This is obviously not a good user experience so I would like to know **how to add a loading screen until the environment shows up and preferably not freeze the UI** because I want to find opponents in the backend as well as the user be able to cancel.

I currently have the entire views of game screen load in viewDidLoad. If you could provide an loading page example either a view or viewController that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom UIKit progress bar to add some better affects and called a progressUpdate to move the bar.  A gameNodes (sharedInstance) class where I cache and share node information with other classes.  gameNodes->loadModels() does a call back every N/Total to update the bar.  In gameViewController->viewDidLoad, I loaded the models after I created UIKit components and aligned them.  I tried a splash screen to help, but I must have done it wrong because it never really worked.  There is some wait time because scenekit had to load (in my case), so it wasn't perfect on all devices.  However, it did produce what I felt like was reasonable feedback as the models were loading.